# Spyon with returnValue() execute original function but no desired value

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Hello devs i have been doing some tutorials for unit testing but i have a problem trying to do UT to a http call example when i do the test to the function inside my component it returns the original value of the function but no the value that i want it to return doing spyOn(x,x).and.returnValue(X) somebody could help me?

this is my component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './entrega.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./entrega.component.css']
})
export class EntregaComponent implements OnInit {
 idEntrega:any='';
 foto:any='';
 urlCasillero='';
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  
   this.urlCasillero=environment.URLCASILLERO;
   this.idEntrega = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
 }


 peticionFoto(data:string):string{
   let foto:string='';
   
     fetch(this.urlCasillero+this.idEntrega).then(res => res.text()).then((text:string) => {
       this.foto=text;
   })
   
 return foto;
 }


}
```

this is my .specs file

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing'; 


import { EntregaComponent } from './entrega.component';

describe('EntregaComponent', () => {
  let component: EntregaComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EntregaComponent>;


  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ EntregaComponent ],
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule  ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EntregaComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });


  it('debe obtener una foto', () => {
    spyOn(component,"peticionFoto").and.returnValue(
      "foto"
    );
      expect(component.foto).toBe('foto');
    });

    
 
});
```

and this is my jasmine result for ng Test

```
EntregaComponent > debe obtener una foto

Expected '' to be 'foto'.

Error: Expected '' to be 'foto'.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/pages/entrega/entrega.component.spec.ts:36:30)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:287:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing or not calling the function explicitly for `foto` to be defined. Also, `return foto` would only make sense if we assign this function call to a variable.

I would make the following changes.

I would use HttpClient instead of fetch, Angular provides this HttpClient for us to make unit testing easier.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './entrega.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./entrega.component.css']
})
export class EntregaComponent implements OnInit {
 idEntrega:any='';
 foto:any='';
 urlCasillero='';
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.urlCasillero=environment.URLCASILLERO;
   this.idEntrega = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
 }


 peticionFoto(data:string): void {
   this.httpClient.get(this.urlCasillero+this.idEntrega).pipe(
     // might not be needed, this map
     map(res => res.text()),
   ).subscribe(result => {
     console.log(result); // make sure the result is what you would like
     this.foto = result;
   });
 }
}
```

And for the test:

```
import { EntregaComponent } from './entrega.component';

describe('EntregaComponent', () => {
  let component: EntregaComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EntregaComponent>;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;


  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ EntregaComponent ],
      // !! Add HttpClientTestingModule !!
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule  ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    // get an instance of http testing controller
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EntregaComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });


  it('debe obtener una foto', fakeAsync(() => {
   // call the function
   component.peticionFoto('abc');
   // expect a get request   
   const request = httpTestingController.expectOne(request => request.method === 'GET');
   // flush this response
   request.flush({ text: () => 'abc' });
   // wait for subscriptions to complete   
   tick();
   expect(component.foto).toBe('abc');
  }));
 
});
```

I did everything without an IDE so there might be mistakes. That being said, I have found this resource https://testing-angular.com/ very good for learning unit testing.